# Keyboard does not show anything on Angular PWA mat-input-field

Tags: html, ios, angular, web, progressive-web-apps

We currently have the following problem in our Angular 6 PWA:

When the user enters a `mat-form-field`, the iOS keyboard shows up, but it does not show anything except the top bar of the layout. It seems like this problem only appears in **iOS 13.1.3**, but we cannot find any solution to fix this bug and we also cannot reproduce this issue in any other iOS version. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmEGe.jpg) is how the keyboard looks like after clicking the input field.
Recently, apple about the problem that iOS 13 contains some strange permission issues with third-party keyboards (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210613). They also said that version 13.1.1 solved these problems. We have not installed a third-party keyboard on our testing device.

This is one of the affected elements:

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="searchForm.controls.wildcard">
  <input type="text" matInput placeholder="{{ 'search.wildcard' | translate }}" formControlName="wildcard" />
  <mat-error *ngIf="searchForm.controls.wildcard.hasError('required')">
    {{ 'search.wildcard.error.required' | translate }} <strong>{{ 'basic.required' | translate }}</strong>
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="searchForm.controls.wildcard.hasError('validateNotEmpty')"> {{ 'validation.not-empty' | translate }} </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?